# gcc - What does ../ (dot dot slash) mean in a variable in a Makefile?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I have searched for hours for an answer to this. I am new to gcc and Makefiles.

I have a Makefile in some source code that looks like this:

```
CC=gcc
SRCDIR=src
BINDIR=../bin
CFLAGS= -flag
LIBS= -lthing
...
$(BINDIR)/program_name: $(SRCDIR)/program_name.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(SRCDIR)/program_name.c -o $(BINDIR)/program_name $(LIBS)
```

I understand what all of this means except what ../ in `BINDIR` is meant to do. When I make the Makefile, I get the error message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file ../bin/program_name: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:20: recipe for target '../bin/program_name' failed
make: *** [../bin/program_name] Error 1
```

My guess is that the original author of this Makefile meant that the bin folder should go in the parent directory of where the Makefile is located. I know when using the Linux CLI command `cd` that the dot dot means go up a directory. Is that what this is trying to achieve?

Comment: It's means the exact same thing as when used in a shell, i.e. the parent directory.

Comment: Does that mean I need to add to the Makefile to create the bin folder?

Comment: Yes - that's right. You need a rule to make that directory or else you won't be able to put `program_name` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automatically create the `$(BINDIR)` directory before it is actually needed you must declare it as a prerequisite (dependence) of any target that uses it. But each time its content changes its timestamp also changes. So, declaring it as a *regular* prerequisite is not the best thing to do because the targets depending on it would be re-built without real reason, just because the content of `$(BINDIR)` changed.

This is why make also supports [order-only prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) (OOPs):

```
$(BINDIR)/program_name: $(SRCDIR)/program_name.c | $(BINDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(BINDIR):
    mkdir -p $@
```

Note the `|` that introduces the list of OOPs. An OOP is built if it does not exist, which causes the targets depending on it to be (re-)built too. But if it exists make does not even consider its last modification time. Even if some target depending on it is older, it is not rebuilt just because of that.

Note: I also used the `$<` and `$@` [automatic variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables). In the rule's recipe they expand as the first prerequisite (`$(SRCDIR)/program_name.c`) and the target (`$(BINDIR)/program_name`), respectively. They are highly recommended: less typing, less errors prone, more generic rules... they have many good properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your makefile is missing a rule to create the `BINDIR` directory - if it doesn't exist, your link line won't be able to put the resulting binary there! A rule like this one should do it:

```
$(BINDIR): 
    mkdir -p $(BINDIR)
```

Just make sure that any other rules (like the one in your question) also depend on this directory!

Comment: I have a rule called `all` that includes a list of the programs like this: `$(BINDIR)/some_program1 \ $(BINDIR)/some_program2`. Do I include `$(BINDIR) \` to the top of that list? From my understanding, that will force the `mkdir` rule execute first?